# Portable Class Library vs Class Library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, portable-class-library, class-library

I am developing new Windows Phone 8.1 application which is using core functionality of my mobile application. (it is a native app and more comprehensive version of it)

My mobile/web application heavily using Class Library which has my domain objects.

I cannot reference class library to WP 8.1 apps, I am creating portable class library and it will have same domain objects as my class library.

Since I wanna keep it DRY, I am thinking move my classes to (whichever is compatible) to portable class library and use this one shared both on web applications and windows store apps.

1- Will be there any compatibility issues with asp.net MVC, WPF, WCF etc?

2- Is it a good move to migrate from class library to portable class library for this reason?

3- Is there any good practice/easy way to move domain classes other than cut/paste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty likely that your class library is using APIs that aren't available in Portable Class Libraries.  You can use the [.NET Portability Analyzer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/08/06/leveraging-existing-code-across-net-platforms.aspx) to analyze your library and see what nonportable APIs it's using.